# Designing this card view in HTML-CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a PSD which I am converting to HTML/CSS - I have tried 4 or 5 different methods but none of them are correct - This is what the PSD card looks like, i.e. Expected result:

[image]

This is what I have:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="restaurant-box">
      <div class="restaurant-box-header">
        <img class="restaurant-logo-blur" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-body">
        <img class="restaurant-logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
        <div class="restaurant-box-content">
          <h4>Restaurant Name</h4>
          <span>Pizza, BBQ, Kebab, Halal</span>
          <br/>
          <span>RATING STARTS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-footer">
        DELIVERS IN 45 MINS
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="restaurant-box">
      <div class="restaurant-box-header">
        <img class="restaurant-logo-blur" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-body">
        <img class="restaurant-logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
        <div class="restaurant-box-content">
          <h4>Restaurant Name</h4>
          <span>Pizza, BBQ, Kebab, Halal</span>
          <br/>
          <span>RATING STARTS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-footer">
        DELIVERS IN 45 MINS
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.restaurant-box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-box-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.restaurant-box-body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.restaurant-logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: -45px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -45px;
}

.restaurant-logo-blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100%;
}

.restaurant-box-footer {
  background-color: #e43b36;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

## Could someone please help me set the position of the logo correctly and background blurred logo correctly? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2oog70up/)

Comment: Er, what's a PSD?

Comment: @zipzit a Photoshop file

Comment: As in PhotoShop File ?  that would be a PSF??

Comment: No Photoshop is now '.psd' @zipzit

Comment: @zipzit I have added the Tag i.e. PSD - if you hover over it you will see the defination for PSD

Comment: Er, the point is, best practice is to never, ever used unexplained abbreviations ever. The don't help communicate your message at all.

Comment: Is it not possible for you to just convert the '.psd' into an image file like jpeg or png and upload it onto your website?

Comment: do u want to do it in bootstrap. I think mdl has this way too easy for u https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section

Comment: SO is not a design or coding service. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You've been here long enough to know not to ask such questions.

Comment: @SankarshMakam no - the website I am developing has dynamic data - the images is just a template - the restaurant name, images etc will change so it has to be HTML

Comment: @Rob I am having issues designing it - it is an HTML/CSS issue - I unable to set the position of items

Comment: You haven't stated a specific question or problem other than help you design. Design is not programming.

Comment: @Rob edited the question

Comment: I agree that SO is not a place for "do my work for me", but OP gave it a shot.  @zipzit.... it's perfectly normal to use acronyms and file extensions.

Comment: Yes but... to anyone who doesn't immediately understand the mystery abbreviation, what you've accomplished is just bad communication.  It may be `normal`, but we can all communicate better. I hope you don't talk to your customers that way?  And StackOverflow is a awesome way to share coding across a wide variety of folks.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a customer to necessarily know what a *.psd file is (really depends), but I don't even use photoshop - ever - and you better believe I still know what a *.psd file is. You're telling me a web developer should type out "Joint Photographic Experts Group" instead of jpeg or "Graphics Interchange Format" instead of gif? Come on.

Comment: @zipzit Considering this is a technical forum, understanding commonly used acronyms and file types is assumed. No, I don't talk to my customers in a "technical" manner, but I sure do when it comes to my peers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you can simplify this.

I suggest you rely on gulp/grunt/whatever to add vendor prefixes.

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__blur">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo">
  </div>
  <div class="card__logo">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" width="120" />
  </div>
  <div class="card__info">
    <h4>Restaurant Name</h4>
    <p>Pizza, BBQ, Kebab, Halal</p>
    <p>RATING STARTS</p>
  </div>

  <footer class="card__footer">Delivers in 35 minutes</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  width: 251px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card__blur {
  filter: blur(5px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card h4 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

.card__logo {
  margin: auto;
  width: 120px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.card__info {
  text-align: center;
}

.card__info p {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.card__footer {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Fid:

https://jsfiddle.net/2oog70up/2/

Comment: Amazing!, way better than my answer!

Comment: @Phix what did you mean by `I suggest you rely on gulp/grunt/whatever to add vendor prefixes.`?  Are you talking about template vendors? e.g. bootstrap or wordpress?

Comment: Most people develop alongside something like gulp, grunt, webpack, etc. They are build tools that perform common tasks like minification etc.  For example, gulp-autoprefixer appends these prefixes for you when it runs, allowing you to write less code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, with some editing of your CSS, I got this piece of code:

```css
.restaurant-box {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  position: relative;
}

.restaurant-box-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
}

.restaurant-box-body {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%
}

.restaurant-logo {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 70px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -45px;
}

.restaurant-logo-blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: 100%;
  
}

.restaurant-box-footer {
  background-color: #e43b36;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
   position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="restaurant-box">
      <div class="restaurant-box-header">
        <img class="restaurant-logo-blur" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-body">
        <img class="restaurant-logo" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTDn0TxNUiy1h54cBhyyqWQI2IncNL06a4jizOls9MteYbUBfZC" alt="restaurant-logo" />
        <div class="restaurant-box-content">
          <h4>Restaurant Name</h4>
          <span>Pizza, BBQ, Kebab, Halal</span>
          <br/>
          <span>RATING STARTS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="restaurant-box-footer">
        DELIVERS IN 45 MINS
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n34xt9n1/) on the code. I know it's probably not exactly what you wanted but I do hope it helps.